# How do I delete the first n lines and last line of a file using shell commands?

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep, pipe

I have a file named `Element_query` containing the result of a query :

```
SQL> select count (*) from element;

[Output of the query which I want to keep in my file]

SQL> spool off;
```

I want to delete 1st line and last line using shell command.

Comment: You're probably best off fixing this inside SQL\*Plus; rather than generating a file and then trying to trim the stuff you don't want, you can just tell SQL\*Plus not to generate that stuff to begin with. One approach is described in the "Creating a Flat File" section at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/sqlplus.816/a75664/ch44.htm; another approach is described at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2299375/978917.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i '1d;$d' Element_query
```

**How it works :**

- `-i` option edit the file itself. You could also remove that option and redirect the output to a new file or another command if you want.
- `1d` deletes the first line (`1` to only act on the first line, `d` to delete it)
- `$d` deletes the last line (`$` to only act on the last line, `d` to delete it)

**Going further :**

- You can also delete a range. For example, `1,5d` would delete the first 5 lines.
- You can also delete every line that begins with `SQL>` using the statement `/^SQL> /d`
- You could delete every blank line with `/^$/d`
- Finally, you can combine any of the statement by separating them with a semi-colon (`statement1;statement2;satement3;...`) or by specifying them separately on the command line (`-e 'statement1' -e 'statement 2' ...`)

Comment: If its 3rd line to delete... then i have to use 3d in place of 1d? if its 3rd line from last to delete... then what will be the command?

Comment: How to delete 3rd line from the last using shell commands?

Comment: @Nainita You can specify a range (`1,3d` will delete the first three lines) but it's a little more difficult for the end. Depending on what you want, you could be better off using this : `sed -i '/^SQL> /d' Element_query` to delete lines that begins with `SQL> ` no matter where it is in the file.

Comment: @Nainita - see [my answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209074/52934) for arbitrary tail counts - it offers two solutions for stripping *count* lines as relative to the end of the file. One is a `sed` one-liner - which will work for stripping arbitrary line counts from the head *and* tail of a file, Better though, as long as input is a regular file, is just to group a single input across two `head` processes - it is the fastest way to do this usually.

Comment: I used `sed -i '1d' table-backup.sql` to delete the first line of the sql text file

Comment: is there any limit for the line number, as I tried with some 2.6GB text file, its not removing all the lines, ```sed -i '1,7020934d;$d'  file.log ```

Answer (score 9):

#### head; head

```
{   head -n[num] >/dev/null
    head -n[num]
}  <infile >outfile
```

With the above you can specify the first number of lines to strip off of the head of the output w/ the first `head` command, and the number of lines to write to *`outfile`* with the second. It will also typically do this faster than `sed` - especially when input is *large* - despite requiring two invocations. Where `sed` definitely *should* be preferred though, is in the case that `<infile` is *not* a regular, *lseekable* file - because this will typically *not* work as intended in that case, but `sed` can handle all output modifications in a single, scripted process.

With a GNU `head` you can use the `-` negative form for *`[num]`* in the second command as well. In which case the following command will strip first and last lines from input:

```
{   head -n1 >/dev/null
    head -n-1
}  <infile >outfile
```

#### OR with a POSIX `sed`:

Say, for example, I was reading an input of 20 lines and I wanted to strip the first 3 and the last 7. If I resolved to do so w/ `sed`, I would do it with a tail buffer. I would first add together three and seven for a total strip count of ten and then do:

```
seq 20 | sed -ne:n -e '3d;N;1,10bn' -eP\;D
```

That is an example which strips the first 3 and last 7 lines from input. The idea is that you can buffer as many lines as you wish to strip from the tail of input in the pattern space on a stack but only `P`rint the first of these for every line pulled in.

- On lines `1,10` `sed` `P`rints nothing because for each of those it is stacking input in pattern space line-by-line in a `b`ranch loop.
- On the 3rd line all of `sed`'s stack is `d`eleted - and so the first 3 lines are stripped from output in one fell swoop.
- When `sed` reaches the `$`last line of input and attempts to pull in the `N`ext it hits EOF and stops processing entirely. But at that time pattern space contains all of lines `14,20` - none of which have yet been `P`rinted, and never are.
- On every other line `sed` `P`rints only up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space, and `D`eletes same before beginning a new cycle with what remains - or the next 6 lines of input. The 7th line is appended again to the stack with the `N`ext command in the new cycle.

And so, of `seq`'s output *(which is 20 sequentially numbered lines)*, `sed` only prints:

```
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

This gets to be problematic when the number of lines you desire to strip from the tail of input is large - because `sed`'s performance is directly proportional to the size of its pattern space. Still, though, it is a viable solution in many cases - and POSIX specs a `sed` pattern space to handle at least 4kb before busting.

Comment: gnu `tail` also supports the extended `tail -n+<num>` syntax meaning "start from line `<num>`"

Answer (score 7):

Try this solution:

```
tail -n +2 name_of_file | head -n-1
```

**Customization**

You can easily adapt it to delete the n first lines changing the `+2` of ***`tail`***;
or to delete the last n lines changing the `-1` of ***`head`***.

Comment: This solution is incorrect as it prints the first line.

Comment: @xhienne  Sorry, it was a mistake. I wrote 1 instead of 2 as the parameter of "tail".

Now it works, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

`ed` is 'the standard text editor' and should be available on systems that don't have GNU `sed`. It was originally designed as a text editor, but it is well-suited to scripting.

```
printf '%s\n' 1d '$d' w q | ed Element_query
```

`1d` deletes the first line of the file, `$d` (quoted so that the shell doesn't think it's a variable) deletes the last line, `w` writes the file and `q` quits `ed`. `printf` is here used to format the commands for `ed` -- each is required to be followed by a newline; there are of course other ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

You can select the lines between a range in `awk` (this assumes you know how many lines there are):

```
awk 'NR>1 && NR < 3' file
```

Or in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if $.>1 && $.<3' file
```

If you don't know how many lines there are, you can calculate it on the fly using `grep` (note that this will not count blank lines, use `grep -c '' file` to count them as well):

```
awk -vm="$(grep -c . file2.txt)" 'NR>1 && NR<m' file2.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to answer how to delete a number of lines.  I'm going to attack the problem this way:

`grep -v '#SQL>' Element_query >outfile`

Instead of counting lines, it eliminates the SQL commands by recognizing the prompts.  This solution can then be generalized for other output files of SQL sessions with more commands than just two.

Comment: I like it. I don't know much about SQL - but is there no chance of the prompts occurring at the head of its output lines otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

You'd be far better served by *cutting away* the SQL commands. You can do this in two ways:

1. If you are **absolutely sure** that the sequence "`SQL>`" does *not* occur anywhere else in the output,

   ```
   grep -v -F 'SQL> ' < infile > outfile
   ```
2. If you aren't as sure,

   ```
   grep -v '^SQL> .*;$' < infile > outfile
   ```

The second version is slower but more accurate: it will ignore lines exactly beginning with "SQL> " and ending in semicolon, which seem to describe the lines you want eliminated.

However, it would be better not to put that extra output in the file to begin with. Most SQL systems have some way of doing that. I'm not too conversant with Oracle, but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033943/spool-command-do-not-output-sql-statement-to-file) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to remove leading and trailing line(s) from a file.

You can use `awk` as it handles both pattern matching and line counting,

```
#you need to know length to skip last line, assume we have 100 lines
awk 'NR>1 && NR<100 {print $0};' < inputfile
#or
awk '/SQL/ {next}; {print $0;};' < inputfile |awk 'NR>1&& NR<10 {print $0};'
```

You can use `grep -v` to exclude lines you don't want by pattern, and you can match multiple patterns using the `-E` option,

```
grep -v -E "SQL>" < inputfile > outputfile
```

You can use `head` and `tail` to trim specific counts of lines,

```
lines=$((`wc -l < inputfile`-2)) #how many lines in file, less 2
head -n-1 < inputfile | head -n$lines > outputfile
#or
tail -n+2 < inputfile | head -n$lines > outputfile
```

You could use `vi/vim`, and delete the first and last line(s),

```
vi inputfile
:1
dd
:$
dd
:w! outputfile
:x
```

you could use a perl script, skip the first line, save each line, print when you get a next line,

```
#left as exercise for the reader :-)
```

Comment: For the `head`s you don't actually need the pipe, and, in fact it's better not to use it at all if you can get away with it. When you do `head | head` - while the two processes can run concurrently, they're also both processing practically all of the same data redundantly. If you do instead `{ head >dump; head >save; } <in` you only skip by offset - the first reads 10 lines out to `>dump` and the second reads the *next* 10 lines out to `>save`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
< inputfile awk 'NR>1 {print r}; {r=$0}' > outputfile
```

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `awk`'s `stdin`
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `awk`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`
- `NR>1`: executes the following actions only if the number of the record being processed is greater than 1
- `{print r}`: prints the content of the variable `r`
- `{r=$0}`: assigns the content of the record being processed to the variable `r`

So at the first execution of the `awk` script, the first block of actions is not executed, while the second block of actions is executed and the content of the record is assigned to the variable `r`; at the second execution, the first block of actions is executed, and the content of the variable `r` is printed (so the previous record is printed); this has the effect of printing each processed lines but the first one and the last one.

Comment: You are not excluding the first line. At NR==2, you print the first line of input which stored in `r`.