# How to print few lines from middle of a file using unix shell commands?

Tags: sed, awk, wc

My file contains the following lines,

```
$BQ  
{ VOL       @home    }  
database    daba  
relation    tcdeatid  
opendb  
clear    
.lruno := 72         <-- (This line lruno. := 72 has 10 times in my file1)
.infno := 1  
.tid.noel := 101       
writedb       
clear  
.lruno := 72  
.infno := 205  
.tid.noel := 191      
writedb       
clear    
$EOF
```

In file no.2, I want only this part mentioned below from file1.

```
$BQ  
{ VOL       @home    }  
database    daba  
relation    tcdeatid  
opendb  
clear
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 1  
.tid.noel := 101  
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 205  
.tid.noel := 191
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 0  
.tid.noel := 1111  
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 56  
.tid.noel := 231
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 45  
.tid.noel := 61  
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 23  
.tid.noel := 901
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 123  
.tid.noel := 1611  
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 786  
.tid.noel := 81
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 55  
.tid.noel := 1  
.lruno := 72           
.infno := 253  
.tid.noel := 121
writedb       
clear  
$EOF
```

I want this chunk of lines (lruno. := 72) in a another file using shell commands from file1. I want the command which will read file and count how many times has lruno. := 72 in file1 and write it down the total to another file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete the first n lines and last line of a file using shell commands?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209068/how-do-i-delete-the-first-n-lines-and-last-line-of-a-file-using-shell-commands)

Comment: What are your criteria for selecting the lines you want to keep or delete?

Comment: I dont want to delete any lines from file... I just want to print particular lines which containing lruno := 72 in my file2 (It has 10 times in my file1) from file1. I dont written the whole in file1 but my the output file2 I have shown in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using sed

By selecting the lines starting with `.lruno := 72` and continuing to the next `clear`, this produces the output you request:

```
$ sed -n '/.lruno := 72/,/clear/p' file
.lruno := 72
.infno := 1
.tid.noel := 101
.tid.info := 64
.tid.setnr := 1225
.typeidm := 1
.sourcetable := 2
writedb
clear
.lruno := 72
.infno := 205
.tid.noel := 101
.tid.info := 76
.tid.setnr := 1225
.typeidm := 1
.sourcetable := 2
writedb
clear
```

How it works: `-n` tells sed not to print unless we ask it to.  `/.lruno := 72/,/clear/p` tells it to print all ranges that start with `.lruno := 72` and end with `clear`.

#### Using awk

The same approach works using awk:

```
awk '/.lruno := 72/,/clear/' file
```

Just as in sed, `/.lruno := 72/,/clear/` selects groups of lines starting with `.lruno := 72` and ending with `clear`.  Since no action is specified for those selected lines, awk performs its default action which is to print them.

Comment: Great.. That's exactly what I was looking for... @john1024

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
< inputfile sed '1,6d; $d' > outputfile
```

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `sed`'s `stdin`
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `sed`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`
- `1,6d`: deletes all lines from the 1st to the 6th inclusive
- `$d`: deletes the last line

Sample output:

```bsh
~/tmp$ cat inputfile
$BQ
{ VOL @home }
database daba
relation tcdeatid
opendb
clear
.lruno := 72
.infno := 1
.tid.noel := 101
.tid.info := 64
.tid.setnr := 1225
.typeidm := 1
.sourcetable := 2
writedb
clear
.lruno := 72
.infno := 205
.tid.noel := 101
.tid.info := 76
.tid.setnr := 1225
.typeidm := 1
.sourcetable := 2
writedb
clear
.lruno := 18
.infno := 2
.tid.noel := 100
.tid.info := 34
.tid.setnr := 125
.typeidm := 9
.sourcetable := 2
writedb
clear
.lruno := 18
.infno := 25
.tid.noel := 1101
.tid.info := 71
.tid.setnr := 1425
.typeidm := 1
.sourcetable := 3
writedb
clear
$EOF
~/tmp$ < inputfile sed '1,6d; $d'
.lruno := 72
.infno := 1
.tid.noel := 101
.tid.info := 64
.tid.setnr := 1225
.typeidm := 1
.sourcetable := 2
writedb
clear
.lruno := 72
.infno := 205
.tid.noel := 101
.tid.info := 76
.tid.setnr := 1225
.typeidm := 1
.sourcetable := 2
writedb
clear
.lruno := 18
.infno := 2
.tid.noel := 100
.tid.info := 34
.tid.setnr := 125
.typeidm := 9
.sourcetable := 2
writedb
clear
.lruno := 18
.infno := 25
.tid.noel := 1101
.tid.info := 71
.tid.setnr := 1425
.typeidm := 1
.sourcetable := 3
writedb
clear
~/tmp$
```