# How to skip the first line of my output?

Tags: wc

Here is the issue, I would like to count the number of jobs I have in the hpc, but it is not one of the readily provided features. So I made this simple script

```csh
squeue -u user_name | wc -l
```

where `squeue` prints all the jobs like the following

```csh
> squeue -u user_name
   JOBID PARTITION NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
 8840441    theory cteq      fxm PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
 8840442    theory cteq      fxm PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
 8840443    theory cteq      fxm PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
 8840444    theory cteq      fxm PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
```

which would be piped to `wc` and the number of lines would be counted. However, the first line is not an entry of the job. How may I instruct `wc` to skip the first line when counting? Or should I just take the output of `wc` and minus one to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Referring to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209070/376814), you would do `squeue -u user_name | sed '1d' | wc -l`. Although, there are many very nice solutions in the answers of this question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are many many ways to do this, the first I thought of was:

```
squeue -u user_name | tail -n +2 | wc -l
```

From the man page for `tail`:

```
-n, --lines=[+]NUM            output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10;
                              or use -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```

So fo you -n +2 should skip the first line.

You can also use the sort form of tail: `tail +2`

Comment: `tail` crossed my mind, but don't remember having seen or considered the +n option. For both the idea+explanation and reference: Good one!

Comment: @Mr.Donutz `head` has a similar `+` flag that leaves off some number of rows. I always have a hard time remembering which does what though.

Comment: I prefer `sed 1d` bc i have a hard time remembering the counting directions of head and tail

Comment: @Ben: Great call. The OP didn't say which OS. I have some AIX boxes and tail -n +2 doesn't work on them. sed 1d does.

Answer (score 45):

You can supress the header line from `squeue` with the `-h`-option. That would eliminate the need to remove the first row.

From the [man page of squeue](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/squeue/):

```
-h, --noheader
    Do not print a header on the output.
```

Comment: Or add an option to `squeue` like `-n` to simply output the count directly.

Comment: @Scot you should make that an answer. I would upvote.

Comment: Thanks, @Bex - think it’s too much a derivative of your answer. Maybe if there was code present, I’d make an answer to add the code to do so, but without that, I’ll leave it as a comment on yours...

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun.
You can subract 1 from the wc output

```
echo $(( $(squeue -u user_name|wc -l)-1 ))
```

or

```
squeue -u user_name|wc -l|awk '{print $0-1}'
```

When you use awk you can count the lines with awk and so avoid wc

```
squeue -u user_name|awk 'END{print NR-1}'
```

END means, that the following block is executed after all lines are read and NR means the number of lines read so far.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are a couple of ways to achieve the same result. One other way is to pipe the output of the sequence command to sed, just like below

`squeue -u user_name | sed '1d' | wc -l`